# Why is there no performance_schema.threads?

Tags: performance, mariadb, ubuntu

I am trying to diagnose an issue where a phpBB message board hangs (becomes unresponsive) for about five minutes about once every hour.  (It is not exactly on the hour every hour, but it is a little bit less than hourly, i.e., it's a bit more than one hour between outages.)  The outage can be seen as spikes (to 100%) in CPU/memory usage on the usage graphs.  It seems to be a MySQL query at issue.  The MariaDB version is "Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.6.12-MariaDB".  I have been trying to diagnose what the query might be using the advice given [here](https://www.percona.com/blog/a-simple-approach-to-troubleshooting-high-cpu-in-mysql/).  Unfortunately, when I login to the MySQL interface and run the query

`select * from performance_schema.threads where THREAD_OS_ID = <tid> \G`

(where `<tid>` is the CPU-hogging TID delivered using `pidstat -t -p <mysqld_pid> 1`, and `<mysqld_pid>` is found using `ps -ef | grep 'mysql'`)

I get the result "Empty set".  What am I doing wrong?  (I am definitely running the query before the thread with that TID disappears.)

Comment: If your lucky enough to see a CPU hogging thread, [SHOW EXPLAIN FOR {connection}](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/show-explain/) can give an idea on what its executing.

Comment: possiby the performance schema isn't enabled. It can be at runtime by following the [docs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/performance-schema-overview/).

Comment: @danblack I had no idea it wasn't enabled by default.  If you post this as the answer, I will accept it as answered.  (But, BTW, from what I read in the docs, it CANNOT be enabled at runtime.)

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using the [*SlowLog*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#slow_queries_and_slowlog), with `long_query_time = 1`.

That will  help you locate the naughty query after the fact.

You mentioned "outage" -- I assume it just a slowdown, not really a crash that requires reboot or restarting of mysqld?

If it is a crash, be logged in as root before the next event and repeatedly do `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST`, in hopes of catching the naughty query.

Check `cron` jobs and `EVENTs` to see if something is being started up just before the "hour".  If so, focus on it.